# How to set selected page react-paginate

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-paginate

When I load page with url zbcxyz?page=3. I get params page with searchParams.get("page").
I want to set selected page = 3. Tks [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK8EG.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dmxB.png)
I tried using focrePage but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need pass `initialPage` props

```js
<ReactPaginate
      nextLabel="next >"
      initialPage={(parseInt(searchParams.get("page")) || 1) - 1}
      />
```

Comment: wow thank you, it working. But khi use it. console.log write `You should call navigate() in a React.useEffect(), not when your component is first rendered...` it issue?

Comment: Great ...  I'm think it's related to another plugin. It will be issue when execute `navigate()` method on each rerender